# Verify XML file signature using OpenSSL

Tags: openssl, cryptography, certificate, digital-signature, public-key-encryption

I have a signed XML document and the public key of the certificate used to sign it. I want to verify the signature of the XML file using only OpenSSL from CLI. I tried the command:

```
openssl rsautl -verify -in signed.xml -inkey public_key.pem -pubin
```

but it outputs the error:

```
RSA operation error
139662304335680:error:0406706C:rsa routines:rsa_ossl_public_decrypt:data greater than mod len:crypto/rsa/rsa_ossl.c:609:
```

The error is probably related to the issue of rsautl as the manuals tell us it can only handle small data.
Another command I tried:

```
openssl dgst -verify public_key.pem -signature signed.xml to_sign.xml
```

But this one requires one more file(assumably binary) as argument, which is probably for detached signatures(my signature is **enveloped**). The signature is checked by other means and is valid. Can I know what is the mistake in my commands and if I can do this by `openssl`. Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

XML digsig is actually a complete protocol that defines a container format together with correct ways of generating that container format and verifying its correctness (although it is seriously lacking in that regard, having created a verifying application myself).

So XML digsig *uses* the RSA algorithm / verification internally. However, it is **not** the same thing as just signing / verifying a file. RSA may be used internally, but only specific parts of the XML are being signed, additional information about the signature is added, and the signature is definitely not placed at the end of the XML file, because the result would obviously not be valid XML anymore (as it should end by closing the first/topmost tag).

So no, you cannot use `openssl` command line to verify signed XML files that use this protocol as it is not implemented. You can implement it yourself using `openssl` as tool (although using the OpenSSL API would make more sense),  but you're better off looking for an alternative library that does implement the [XML digsig standard](https://www.w3.org/TR/xmldsig-core1/). That library could use OpenSSL or any other low level crypto library for the underlying algorithms.

Comment: [This lib](https://www.aleksey.com/xmlsec/faq.html) seems to use OpenSSL. Unfortunately that's not the only dependency and I haven't used it, mainly because I think that mixing C (or any other language that doesn't limit memory access) and XML is an *extremely bad idea*. The number of overflows and such in ASN.1 encoding / decoding in C are bad enough, I don't even want to know what that does for XML.